# Highchart plotOption click event only fired once with mouse stay in the block

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Recently I worked on a pie graph and want to toggle pie part, the code is looks like this:

```
                                point: {
                                events: {
                                    click: function () {
                                        //do some stuff
                                        $scope.$apply();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```

It works when you mouse enter the pie part and a halo shows indicate you mouse is hover on it. However, after you clicked, the halo disappeared and it loose focus, then you click again, it won't work. To make it work again, you have to move your mouse somewhere else and enter again to change it to hover state again.
Is there any way to make the click function continue work even you do not move your mouse out and enter again?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is trigger mouseout/mouseover in click event.

```
point: {
    events: {
      click: function(event) {
        toggleProductHide(event.point.name);
        this.onMouseOut();
        this.onMouseOver(event);
      }
    }
  }
```